# Electrical problem with Ford Fiesta diesel

Tags: electrical, ford, fiesta

While driving my Ford Fiesta Classic diesel engine car, I lose all the acceleration.
The RPM meter gets stuck on 2 and all other readings were reset automatically in the speedometer? What could be the problem? Could there be a problem with the MAF sensor?

Comment: I have the same problem - MAF replaced but still experiencing issues. Have you had any luck?